# windows: pip: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013]

Tags: windows, pip, python-3.8

I have installed python on windows 10 64 bit computer

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python --version
Python 3.8.6

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip --version
pip 20.2.1 from c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

So python and pip are installed and are working.

Now i wanted to install notebook (or for that matter any package) using cmd prompt as admin

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install notebook
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002156655FBB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/notebook/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002156655FD60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/notebook/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002156652CB20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/notebook/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021566552A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/notebook/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000215665527F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/notebook/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement notebook (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for notebook

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I get the above error.

I keep getting the same error irrespective of any package name, even pandas

I have searched for solutions the problem is not addresses clearly anywhere

i also tried:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026D8ABC41C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026D8ABC4940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026D8ABE95E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026D8ABE9790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026D8ABE9940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/pip/
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages (20.2.1)
```

Any idea how to solve this problem

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: I even tried that. see my edited question

Comment: Do yo have jupyter installed?